# Проблема при создании пакета struct.pack()

Tags: python, struct

Мне надо создать пакет для сервера Minecraft (подробнее о этом [https://minecraft-ru.gamepedia.com/Протокол_сервера_Classic](https://minecraft-ru.gamepedia.com/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_Classic)).
Мой код:

```
import socket
import struct

username = "123123123"
verification_key = "123123123"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("SLeZH.aternos.me", 25565))
packet = ""

packet += struct.pack(">B", 1)
packet += struct.pack(">B", 7)
packet += "%-64s" % username
packet += "%-64s" % verification_key
packet += struct.pack(">B", 0)

s.send(packet)
```

А ошибка такая:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nokim\Desktop\example.py", line 12, in <module>
    packet += struct.pack(">B", 1)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

Как это можно исправить? Заранее спасибо

upd: забыл сказать что я собираю пакет "Идентификация игрока"

Comment: packet = " " тоесть ты создаешь строку, а пытаешься писать в нее байты. Можно сделать так packet = bytes() . Тоже самое касается срок packet += "%-64s" % username packet += "%-64s" % verification_key только тут проблема обратная, ты пытаешься добавлять строки к байтам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы инициализируете пакет как строку `packet = ""`, а `struct.pack()` возвращает байты. Ошибка вам и говорит о том что нельзя просто взять и сложить строку и байты. Также метод сокета `send` принимает на вход байты, а не строку, поэтому в любом случае все части пакета нужно преобразовывать в байты.

В данном случае можно собрать пакет за один вызов `struct.pack()`:

```
# Пробелы в "> B B 64s 64s B" добавил для лучшей читаемости. На конечный результат эти пробелы не влияют.
packet = struct.pack("> B B 64s 64s B", 1, 7,  
                     username.encode().ljust(64, b' '),
                     verification_key.encode().ljust(64, b' '), 0)
```

Если строки могут содержать не только латиницу, нужно указать правильную кодировку как аргумент `encode` (судя по информации по ссылке, которую вы указали в вопросе, это не требуется).

На всякий случай добавлю исправленный вариант сборки пакета по частям:

```
packet = bytes()

packet += struct.pack(">B", 1)
packet += struct.pack(">B", 7)
packet += username.encode().ljust(64, b' ')
packet += verification_key.encode().ljust(64, b' ')
packet += struct.pack(">B", 0)
```

Результат будет одним и тем же в обоих вариантах.